# how can i prohibit my electron to register with protocol handler while running directly from IDE?

Tags: javascript, electron

I have an electron app which i register with protocol handler using below code in main.js

```
app.setAsDefaultProtocolClient('xyz');
```

When i tried to run it from installed location all works as expected .But  launching it from visual studio code messed up the protocol handler(As while running from IDE like VS code it name the app as a electron app instead of the name I defined) as a result of which next time when I try running from installed location the protocol handler tries to find a different app which is default "Electron" app.Is there any way i can avoid this from happening .

I tried putting an if statement to check if the app.name and my expected name is same but this always returns true  though i see the app name as Electron on my os.Any clue here will be helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`app.isPackaged`](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/app#appispackaged-readonly).

> A Boolean property that returns true if the app is packaged, false otherwise. For many apps, this property can be used to distinguish development and production environments.